# How to determine if Python is available in HPUX system?

Tags: python, hp-ux

How can I know if the environment that I am in (some version of HPUX) has python installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If python is in your PATH-Environment variable (if it is properly installed, it should be), you could use one of the following three:

```
python --version
which python
Whereis python
```

1. Calls python --version
2. Shows the path that is called when using `python`
3. Shows all paths to python

If you are unlucky, it is not in your PATH and you actually have to search the whole system to be sure it is not installed somewhere.

```
find / -name python
```

Comment: I haven't used HP-UX in over 10 years, but on most Unices I would try `locate python | grep bin` first.

Answer (score -1):

you can use the swinstall command to list installed packages:
http://www.bga.org/~lessem/psyc5112/usail/man/hpux/swinstall.1.html

and as @jacob said the `which` ,`whereis` and `find` commands are very usefull